# Disable a VIM plugin in a specific directory

Tags: django, vim, vim-plugin

I am aware that it is possible to have project and folder specific .vimrc files, but I can't seem to find the correct command to disable a plugin for a specific directory.

In case it might be a plugin-specific matter, I am trying to disable [AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) in my Django Templates folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's autocmd doesn't support any directory change event.

So you are forced to use some other event, maybe CursorMoved and execute a function that checks if the saved current working directory equals the current working directory.
If not, you can execute your command.

Also, vim isn't made for unloading plugins. But there's a plugin for that! 
https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager

Be aware that this idea is kinda hackish and might result in some serious issues.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I'll look into that or just suck it up until I can come up with a better way to do Django Template tags!

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the plugin's code?

```
let g:autoclose_on=0
```

might do the trick.

Comment: tried that, it doesn't work even if I run it inside the vim buffer. It might be due to the fact that I'm running MacVim with the latest version of [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) and it's loaded via pathogen?